# Rigging a character with accessories like belt

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I'm trying to rig a character but I have problems with the belt and straps of the bag. Somehow the automatic weight paint (?) does not work properly. I did join the meshes of the character and accessories. I tried rigify (prefered option) and some really basic self made rig. As one solution, I can extrude the belt and straps from the character mesh with the knife tool. That would be fine and it should be working but that's not my prefered workflow. Also even if it works right now, I'm not sure if I would add some accessories in the future for which it will not work. How do I fix my problem? By the way, I do have the problem even without the subdivison modifier.

Basic mesh:

[image: basic mesh]

Animated mesh with self made rig:

[image: animated mesh with rig]

Close up of my problem:

[image: close up]

Comment: is the belt part of the character, or its own object?

Comment: It's the same mesh. So it is part of the character. The vertices are not linked tho.

Comment: Maybe link the vertices then?

Comment: As I wrote, which is linking vertices. There should be another solution.

"As one solution, I can extrude the belt and straps from the character mesh with the knife tool. That would be fine and it should be working but that's not my prefered workflow. Also even if it works right now, I'm not sure if I would add some accessories in the future for which it will not work."

Comment: it's not correctly weighted, so paint it in Weight Paint mode, or assign these vertices to the vertex groups there are supposed to be part of and remove them from the groups there are not supposed to be part of, there's no reason it could not work. Another solution would be to give its own bones but this should not be necessary. Maybe share your file so that we can give a try (delete the unnecessary parts if you want).

Comment: Now I'm using weight paint mode and read into vertex groups. That's a lot of work as I have to repeat it for each character, but I can fix it with both. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the data transfer modifer when the belt is a seperate object. Have a look here no need to explain it more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C7eftpocH0